# How to use a predefined function with R.zipWith

Tags: ramda.js

This is the initial data set.

```
const Main = { 
  ratio : [ 0.5, 1, 2 ],
  focusPoint : [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ],
}
```

I want this object calculated with a predefined function.

```
const width =  window.innerWidth
const height = window.innerHeight 
const ratioViewport = width / height
const resultY =  ( x, y )  =>   0.5 * ( x / ratioViewport ) - y
```

Here is the final part with R.zipWith to evaluate the function.

```
const getPositionMain = applySpec ( {
   ratio : R.prop ('ratio'),
   resultY : R.zipWith ( resultY,  R.prop ('ratio') ,  R.prop ('focusPoint') ),
   } )
const positionMain = getPositionMain ( Main )

console.log( 'positionMain : ', positionMain )
```

// Desired output (positionMain) :   [ 0.5 * (1 / ratioViewport) - 0.1, 0.5 * (2 / ratioViewport) - 0.2, 0.5 * (3 / ratioViewport) - 0.3 ]

But, I am not getting it right.
What am I doing wrong at here?

[REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20width%20%3D%20%C2%A0window.innerWidth%0Aconst%20height%20%3D%20window.innerHeight%20%0Aconst%20ratioViewport%20%3D%20width%20%2F%20height%0Aconst%20resultY%20%3D%20%20%28%20x%2C%20y%20%29%20%20%3D%3E%20%20%200.5%20%2A%20%28%20x%20%2F%20ratioViewport%20%29%20-%20y%20%0A%0Aconst%20Main%20%3D%20%7B%20%0A%C2%A0%20ratio%20%3A%20%5B%201%2C%202%2C%203%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20focusPoint%20%3A%20%5B%200.1%2C%200.2%2C%200.3%20%5D%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20getPositionMain%20%3D%20applySpec%20%28%20%7B%0A%20%20%20ratio%20%3A%20prop%20%28%27ratio%27%29%2C%0A%20%20%20result%20%3A%20zipWith%20%28%20resultY%2C%20%20prop%20%28%27ratio%27%29%20%2C%20%20prop%20%28%27focusPoint%27%29%20%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%7D%20%29%0Aconst%20positionMain%20%3D%20getPositionMain%20%28%20Main%20%29%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%20%27positionMain%20%3A%20%27%2C%20positionMain%20%29%0A%0A%0A%2F%2FDesired%20output%20%28positionMain%29%20%3A%20%20%20%5B%200.5%20%2A%20%281%20%2F%20ratioViewport%29%20-%200.1%2C%200.5%20%2A%20%282%20%2F%20ratioViewport%29%20-%200.2%2C%200.5%20%2A%20%283%20%2F%20ratioViewport%29%20-%200.3%20%5D%20%0A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what you want.  Are you looking for something like this?

```js
const getPositionMain = (w, ratioViewport = w.innerWidth / w.innerHeight) => main =>
  zipWith ((x, y) => 0.5 * (x / ratioViewport) - y) (main .ratio, main .focusPoint)


const _window = {innerWidth: 600, innerHeight: 400}
const Main = { 
  ratio : [ 0.5, 1, 2 ],
  focusPoint : [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ],
}

console .log (getPositionMain (_window) (Main))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {zipWith} = R                                         </script>
```

Or something more like this?:

```js
const getPositionMain = (w, ratioViewport = w.innerWidth / w.innerHeight) => (main) => ({
  ratio: main .ratio,
  resultY: zipWith ((x, y) => 0.5 * (x / ratioViewport) - y) (main .ratio, main .focusPoint)
})

const _window = {innerWidth: 600, innerHeight: 400}
const Main = { 
  ratio : [ 0.5, 1, 2 ],
  focusPoint : [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ],
}

console .log (getPositionMain (_window) (Main))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {zipWith} = R                                         </script>
```

In either case, the code is much the same, just with a different format for the output results.

The working version I can get to closest to your attempt would look like this:

```js
const getPositionMain = (w, ratioViewport = w.innerWidth / w.innerHeight) => applySpec ({
  ratio : prop ('ratio'),
  resultY : lift (zipWith ((x, y) => 0.5 * (x / ratioViewport) - y)) 
                 (prop ('ratio') ,  prop ('focusPoint'))
})
```

Note that `zipWith` takes a function and two lists.  You were passing it the initial function and two functions that would resolve to lists when called properly.  Functions that will resolve to specific types can be thought of as *containers* of those types.  `lift` takes a function that operates on values and lifts it up to become a function that operates on containers of those values.  So `lift (resultY) (f, g)` is approximately `main => resultY (f (main), g (main))`, and we can then use it in `applySpec`.

In every version here, I avoid the global variables you have of `ratioViewport`, calculating it from a `Window` object as a parameter.  I find this much cleaner, but YMMV.

But we could skip that variable altogether by performing the inexpensive viewport calculation inside the main function, like this:

```js
const getPositionMain = ({innerWidth, innerHeight}) => ({ratio, focusPoint}) =>
  zipWith ((x, y) => 0.5 * (x / innerWidth * innerHeight) - y, ratio, focusPoint)
```

or like this:

```js
const getPositionMain = ({innerWidth, innerHeight}) => ({ratio, focusPoint}) => ({
  ratio,
  resultY: zipWith ((x, y) => 0.5 * (x / innerWidth * innerHeight) - y, ratio, focusPoint)
})
```

Those are the versions I prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I want to use the `const ratioViewport = width / height ` because this is reused many times in my another function. I need to get used to joining arrow functions.

Comment: @Rio: Another reasonable possibility would be to make the signature `(ratioViewport) => (main) => ...` and then pass in the stored result of that calculation.  If you need to reuse the function `resultY`, which uses this other value, then you can write `resultY = getResultY(ratioViewport)` where `getResultY` something like `(ratioViewport) => (x, y) => 0.5 * ...`.  These techniques leave your functions independently testable and keep down coupling between them.

Comment: I looked into `lift` function, and it worked better for me. So, this is the final cut. `resultY : lift (zipWith (resultY)) (prop ('ratio') ,  prop ('focusPoint'))` . Your guidance helped  me a lot. Thanks again.